# Cascading dropdown in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to populate another dropdownlist from a dropdown list, i keep getting error "TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return CompanySelected }" and "http://localhost/xxx/api/Transaction/LoadInsurancePolicies/undefined 400 (Bad Request)". Insurance Policy must be populated when Insurance company is chosen. this is the code below

```
  self.InsuranceCompanyId = ko.observable();
  self._companySelected= ko.observable(null);
  self.CompanySelected = ko.computed({
  read:  function () {return this._companySelected()  },
  write: function (value) {
  $.ajax({
         url: baseUrl + 'api/Transaction/LoadInsurancePolicies/' + 
         value.InsuranceCompanyId,
         type: 'GET',
         headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
         if (data.Successfull == 1) 
         {
         self.AllPolicies(data.Model); } },
         error: function (request, error) {                
         }
        });

        this._companySelected(value);
    },
    owner: this     
    });
    self.AllInsuranceCompanies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AllPolicies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.LoadInsuranceCompanies = function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: baseUrl + 'api/Transaction/LoadInsuranceCompanies',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            if (data.Successfull == 1) {
                self.AllInsuranceCompanies(data.Model);
                console.log(data);
            }

        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
  }
 self.LoadInsuranceCompanies();

 this is my view

  <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible:(InputOption()==0)">
  <label for="InputTxt" class="control-label col-md-4">Insurance 
  Company</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <select data-bind="options: AllInsuranceCompanies,
                  optionsText: 'Name',
                  optionsValue:'Id',
                  optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                  value:CompanySelected,
                  valueUpdate:'change'"  class="form-control">
                  </select>
                   </div>
                   </div>
  <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible: (InputOption()==0)">
  <label for="InputTxt" class="control-label col-md- 
  4">InsurancePolicy</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <select data-bind="options: AllPolicies,
                    optionsText: 'Name',
                    optionsValue:'Id',
                    value: selectedPolicy,
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" class="form-control"> 
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: did you try using `_companySelected`

Comment: U mean i should use it on the value of the view.replace CompanySelected with CompanySelected??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution gave me an idea.I passed a **function(value)** and the value will be the selected Id,add it to the api as a parameter and it gets me the results.

```
self.insuranceCompanyId = ko.observable('');
self.selectedPolicy = ko.observable();  
self._companySelected = ko.observable();
self.CompanySelected = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {

        return this._companySelected()
    },

    write: function (value) {
        console.log("inside write", value)

        if (value) {
            console.log('data');
            $.ajax({

                url: baseUrl + "api/Transaction/LoadInsurancePolicies/" + 
                value,
                type: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.Successfull == 1) {
                        self.AllPolicies(data.Model);
                        console.log(value);
                    }

                },
                error: function (request, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
            this._companySelected(value);
        }

    },

    owner: this

});
self.LoadInsuranceCompanies();
```

Answer (score 2):

The following are probably the problems in your code.

1. `self.CompanySelected` is defined before `self.AllPolicies`. This will cause to have a runtime error since `ko.computed` automatically runs when it is defined. This is based on knockout documentation. Solution: try defining all `ko.observable` before all `ko.computed` or atleast put `self.AllPolicies` before `self.CompanySelected`.
2. Since the `ko.computed` automatically runs, and the value of `self.CompanySelected` is `undefined`, you will also have an `undefined` `InsuranceCompanyId` in your api call and this will result in Bad request 400. Solution: try adding a guard before calling your api. if(value){....}
3. In your html bindings, you put `optionsValue: 'Id'`. This will result in knockout trying to find an `Id` property in your model which probably does not exist. Solution: remove `optionsValue:'Id'` from your bindings so that the value when changing option will be the model object itself and not just the `Id`.

Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/przquhcf/1/ which implements the solutions above.
Note: I just substituted `setTimeout` for your api calls since i dont have access to them. Dont worry about this part.

Comment: Thanks for your help on the code above,the all policies is the result set which must be loaded into another dropdown,but the api keeps telling me undefined for the InsuranceCompanyId.

Comment: ,Thanks for your help on the code above,the AllPolicies is the result set which must be loaded into another dropdown,but the api keeps telling me undefined for the InsuranceCompanyId(this is a column from the database,a foreign key). AllPolicies rather has the property 'InsuranceCompanyId' but AllInsuranceCompanies has the property 'Id'. so when all 'AllInsuranceCompanies' is loaded and when clicked,AllPolicies must be loaded depending on the results from AllInsuranceCompanies.